# Import List<String> into jQuery DataTables with Java and Spring MVC

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, datatables

I am making Spring MVC Web Service, with jQuery DataTables and I have a few List which I have to import into the jQuery DataTables table.

```
public class Elements {

private List<String> dep1;
private List<String> dep2;
private List<String> dep3;
private List<String> dep4;
private List<String> dep5;

private List<String> indep1;
private List<String> indep2;
private List<String> indep3;
private List<String> indep4;
private List<String> indep5;

 public List<String> getDep1() {
        return dep1;
    }

    public void setDep1(List<String> first) {
        this.dep1 = first;
    }

    public List<String> getDep2(){
        return dep2;
    }

    public void setDep2(List<String> dep2){
        this.dep2 = dep2;
    }

    public List<String> getDep3(){
        return dep3;
    }

    public void setDep3(List<String> dep3){
        this.dep3 = dep3;
    }

    public List<String> getDep4(){
        return dep4;
    }

    public void setDep4(List<String> dep4){
        this.dep4 = dep4;
    }

    public List<String> getDep5(){
        return dep5;
    }

    public void setDep5(List<String> dep5){
        this.dep5 = dep5;
    }

    public List<String> getIndep1(){
        return indep1;
    }

    public void setIndep1(List<String> indep1){
        this.indep1 = indep1;
    }

    public List<String> getIndep2(){
        return indep2;
    }

    public void setIndep2(List<String> indep2){
        this.indep2 = indep2;
    }

    public List<String> getIndep3(){
        return indep3;
    }

    public void setIndep3(List<String> indep3){
        this.indep3 = indep3;
    }

    public List<String> getIndep4(){
        return indep4;
    }

    public void setIndep4(List<String> indep4){
        this.indep4 = indep4;
    }

    public List<String> getIndep5(){
        return indep5;
    }

    public void setIndep5(List<String> indep5){
        this.indep5 = indep5;
    }
}
```

This is my JSONClassObject:

```
import java.util.List;

public class ElementsJsonObject {


int iTotalRecords;

int iTotalDisplayRecords;

String sEcho;

String sColumns;

List<Elements> aaData;

public int getiTotalRecords() {
return iTotalRecords;
}

public void setiTotalRecords(int iTotalRecords) {
this.iTotalRecords = iTotalRecords;
}

public int getiTotalDisplayRecords() {
return iTotalDisplayRecords;
}

public void setiTotalDisplayRecords(int iTotalDisplayRecords) {
this.iTotalDisplayRecords = iTotalDisplayRecords;
}

public String getsEcho() {
return sEcho;
}

public void setsEcho(String sEcho) {
this.sEcho = sEcho;
}

public String getsColumns() {
return sColumns;
}

public void setsColumns(String sColumns) {
this.sColumns = sColumns;
}

public List<Elements> getAaData() {
    return aaData;
}

public void setAaData(List<Elements> aaData) {
    this.aaData = aaData;
}


}
```

This is my Controller class:

```
@Controller

public class ElementsController {


@RequestMapping(value = "/elements.web", method = 
    RequestMethod.GET)
public String printWelcome(@ModelAttribute("elements") Elements elements, BindingResult result,ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest 
    request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    return "ListOfElements";

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/elementsPaginationDataTables.web", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody String elementsPaginationDataTables(HttpServletRequest  request) throws IOException {

    //Fetch the page number from client
    Integer pageNumber = 0;
    if (null != request.getParameter("iDisplayStart"))
        pageNumber = (Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("iDisplayStart"))/10)+1;     

    //Fetch search parameter
    String searchParameter = request.getParameter("sSearch");

    //Fetch Page display length
    Integer pageDisplayLength = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("iDisplayLength"));

    //Create page list data
    List<Elements> elementsList = createPaginationData(pageDisplayLength);

    //Here is server side pagination logic. Based on the page number you could make call 
    //to the data base create new list and send back to the client. For demo I am shuffling 
    //the same list to show data randomly
    if (pageNumber == 1) {
        Collections.shuffle(elementsList);
    }else if (pageNumber == 2) {
        Collections.shuffle(elementsList);
    }else {
        Collections.shuffle(elementsList);
    }

    //Search functionality: Returns filtered list based on search parameter
    elementsList = getListBasedOnSearchParameter(searchParameter,elementsList);


    ElementsJsonObject elementsJsonObject = new ElementsJsonObject();
    //Set Total display record
    elementsJsonObject.setiTotalDisplayRecords(500);
    //Set Total record
    elementsJsonObject.setiTotalRecords(500);
    elementsJsonObject.setAaData(elementsList);

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    String json2 = gson.toJson(elementsJsonObject);

    return json2;
}

private List<Elements> getListBasedOnSearchParameter(String searchParameter,List<Elements> elementsList) {

    if (null != searchParameter && !searchParameter.equals("")) {
        List<Elements> elementsListForSearch = new ArrayList<Elements>();
        searchParameter = searchParameter.toUpperCase();
        for (Elements elements : elementsList) {
            if (elements.getDep1().indexOf(searchParameter)!= -1 || elements.getDep2().indexOf(searchParameter)!= -1
                    || elements.getDep3().indexOf(searchParameter)!= -1 || elements.getDep4().indexOf(searchParameter)!= -1
                    || elements.getDep5().indexOf(searchParameter)!= -1 || elements.getIndep1().indexOf(searchParameter)!= -1
                    || elements.getIndep2().indexOf(searchParameter)!= -1 || elements.getIndep3().indexOf(searchParameter)!= -1
                    || elements.getIndep4().indexOf(searchParameter)!= -1 || elements.getIndep5().indexOf(searchParameter)!= -1)
                    {
                elementsListForSearch.add(elements);                    
            }

        }

        elementsList = elementsListForSearch;
        elementsListForSearch = null;
    }

    return elementsList;
}

private List<Elements> createPaginationData(Integer pageDisplayLength) {
    List<Elements> elementsList = new ArrayList<Elements>();

    try{

        File file = new File("C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/tmpFiles/Canon.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Canon.class);      
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Canon canon = (Canon) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

        List<Table> table = canon.getTable();

    for(Table tables: table){

            List<String> row = tables.getRow();

            List<String> first = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> second = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> third = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> fourth = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> fifth = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> sixth = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> seventh = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> eight = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> ninth = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> tenth = new ArrayList<String>();

            String values = null;
            String values2 = null;

            String value1 = null;
            String value2 = null;
            String value3 = null;
            String value4 = null;
            String value5 = null;
            String value6 = null;
            String value7 = null;
            String value8 = null;
            String value9 = null;
            String value10 = null;

            String value11 = null;
            String value22 = null;
            String value33 = null;
            String value44 = null;
            String value55 = null;
            String value66 = null;
            String value77 = null;
            String value88 = null;
            String value99 = null;
            String value1010 = null;

            List<String> rowss = row.subList(0, 12600);
                for(int i=0; i<rowss.size(); i++){
                values = row.get(i);

                String[] parts = values.split(" +");

                String part0 = parts[1];     
                String part1 = parts[2];
                String part2 = parts[3];
                String part3 = parts[4];
                String part4 = parts[5];
                String part5 = parts[6];
                String part6 = parts[7];
                String part8 = parts[8];
                String part9 = parts[9];
                String part10 = parts[10];

                value1 = parts[1];
                value2 = parts[2];
                value3 = parts[3];
                value4 = parts[4];
                value5 = parts[5];
                value6 = parts[6];
                value7 = parts[7];
                value8 = parts[8];
                value9 = parts[9];
                value10 = parts[10];

                first.add(value1);
                second.add(value2);
                third.add(value3);
                fourth.add(value4);
                fifth.add(value5);
                sixth.add(value6);
                seventh.add(value7);
                eight.add(value8);
                ninth.add(value9);
                tenth.add(value10);
                }   

                List<String> row1 = tables.getRow();
               List<String> rows = row1.subList(12600, row1.size());
                for(int j=0; j<rows.size(); j++){

                values2 = rows.get(j);

                String[] parts2 = values2.split(" +");

                String part11 = parts2[0];   
                String part22 = parts2[1];
                String part33 = parts2[2];
                String part44 = parts2[3];
                String part55 = parts2[4];
                String part66 = parts2[5];
                String part77 = parts2[6];
                String part88 = parts2[7];
                String part99 = parts2[8];
                String part1010 = parts2[9];

                value11 = parts2[0];
                value22 = parts2[1];
                value33 = parts2[2];
                value44 = parts2[3];
                value55 = parts2[4];
                value66 = parts2[5];
                value77 = parts2[6];
                value88 = parts2[7];
                value99 = parts2[8];
                value1010 = parts2[9];


                first.add(value11);
                second.add(value22);
                third.add(value33);
                fourth.add(value44);
                fifth.add(value55);
                sixth.add(value66);
                seventh.add(value77);
                eight.add(value88);
                ninth.add(value99);
                tenth.add(value1010);


                }


    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        Elements element = new Elements();

            element.setDep1(first);
            element.setDep2(second);
            element.setDep3(third);
            element.setDep4(fourth);
            element.setDep5(fifth);
            element.setIndep1(sixth);
            element.setIndep2(seventh);
            element.setIndep3(eight);
            element.setIndep4(ninth);
            element.setIndep5(tenth);

            elementsList.add(element);              

    }       

    }
    }

                catch (JAXBException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    return elementsList;
}
}
```

And this is my jsp page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Spring pagination using data tables</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
`<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">`

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


//Plug-in to fetch page data 


jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function ( oSettings )
{


return {
        "iStart":         oSettings._iDisplayStart,
        "iEnd":           oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
        "iLength":        oSettings._iDisplayLength,
        "iTotal":         oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
        "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
        "iPage":          oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ?
            0 : Math.ceil( oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength ),
        "iTotalPages":    oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ?
            0 : Math.ceil( oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength )
    };
};


$(document).ready(function() {


$("#example").dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sort": "position",
    //bStateSave variable you can use to save state on client cookies: set value "true" 
    "bStateSave": false,
    //Default: Page display length
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    //We will use below variable to track page number on server side(For more information visit: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options#iDisplayStart)
    "iDisplayStart": 0,
    "fnDrawCallback": function () {
        //Get page numer on client. Please note: number start from 0 So
        //for the first page you will see 0 second page 1 third page 2...
        //Un-comment below alert to see page number
        //alert("Current page number: "+this.fnPagingInfo().iPage);    
    },         
    "sAjaxSource": "elementsPaginationDataTables.web",
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "dep1" },
        { "mData": "dep2" },
        { "mData": "dep3" },
        { "mData": "dep4" },
        { "mData": "dep5" },
        { "mData": "indep1" },
        { "mData": "indep2" },
        { "mData": "indep3" },
        { "mData": "indep4" },
        { "mData": "indep5" },

    ]
} );


} );



</script>

</head>

<body>

<form:form action="" method="GET">

<h2 >Spring MVC pagination using data tables<br><br></h2>

<table width="70%" style="border: 3px;background: rgb(243, 244, 248);"><tr><td>


<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">


<thead>


<tr>


<th>Dep1</th>
            <th>Dep2</th>
            <th>Dep3</th>
            <th>Dep4</th>
            <th>Dep5</th>
            <th>Indep1</th>
            <th>Indep2</th>
            <th>Indep3</th>
            <th>Indep4</th>
            <th>Indep5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>       
</table>
</td></tr></table>
</form:form>
</body>

</html>
```

The List are between try - catch and it is data from XML file.

My question is how to implement those list into a different cells for each column in the table? When I do `setDep1(first)` I'm getting whole list in one cell in the first column.

How to put each value in a different cell? Maybe i have to mention that `first`, `second`, `third` and so on... to `tenth` has about 45000 values each.

Comment: It seems that you use `dataTable` and **not** `jqGrid` (see JavaScript code which you included).

Comment: Ok,  i agree,  sorry for the confusion,  but how to fill the columns with my list<string> anyway?